# Undefined method `subscriptions' for #<Stripe::Customer:0x00007f1ac4d0b548> / The action 'index' could not be found for SubscriptionsController

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I keep running into these two errors after I submit the card details using Stripe API, and the app should then create a new subscriber and redirects them to the library, but instead I get:

> Undefined method `subscriptions' for #Stripe::Customer:0x00007f1ac4d0b548

and

> The action 'index' could not be found for SubscriptionsController

And I always get the first error first, then when i refresh the page it changes to the second one.

Here's my subscriptions_controller (/app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb):

```
    class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
    layout "subscribe"
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:new, :create]

    def new
      if user_signed_in? && current_user.subscribed?
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "You are already a subscriber!"
      end
    end

    def create
      Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.stripe_api_key

      plan_id = params[:plan_id]
      plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(plan_id)
      token = params[:stripeToken]

      customer = if current_user.stripe_id?
                   Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
                 else
                   Stripe::Customer.create(email: current_user.email, source: token)
                 end

      subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(plan: plan.id)

      options = {
        stripe_id: customer.id,
        stripe_subscription_id: subscription.id,
        subscribed: true,
      }

      options.merge!(
        card_last4: params[:user][:card_last4],
        card_exp_month: params[:user][:card_exp_month],
        card_exp_year: params[:user][:card_exp_year],
        card_type: params[:user][:card_type]
      ) if params[:user][:card_last4]

      current_user.update(options)

      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your subscription was set up successfully!"
    end

    def destroy
      customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
      customer.subscriptions.retrieve(current_user.stripe_subscription_id).delete
      current_user.update(stripe_subscription_id: nil)

      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your subscription has been cancelled."
    end
end
```

Here's my subscribe.html.erb (app/views/layouts/subscribe.html.erb)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= Rails.configuration.application_name %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/','data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= tag :meta, name: "stripe-key", content: Rails.application.credentials.stripe_publishable_key %>
  </head>

  <body class="<%= yield (:body_class) %>">
    <% if flash[:notice] %>
      <div class="notification is-success global-notification">
        <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <% if flash[:alert] %>
    <div class="notification is-danger global-notification">
      <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
    </div>
    <% end %>

     <nav class="navbar is-dark" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <div class="navbar-item">
          <h1 class="title is-5 has-text-white"><%= Rails.configuration.application_name %></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here's /app/views/subscriptions/new.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= Rails.configuration.application_name %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/','data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= tag :meta, name: "stripe-key", content: Rails.application.credentials.stripe_publishable_key %>
  </head>

  <body class="<%= yield (:body_class) %>">
    <% if flash[:notice] %>
      <div class="notification is-success global-notification">
        <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <% if flash[:alert] %>
    <div class="notification is-danger global-notification">
      <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
    </div>
    <% end %>

     <nav class="navbar is-dark" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <div class="navbar-item">
          <h1 class="title is-5 has-text-white"><%= Rails.configuration.application_name %></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

here's the javascript file for subscriptions (app/assets/javascripts/subscriptions.js)

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  const publishableKey = document.querySelector("meta[name='stripe-key']").content;
  const stripe = Stripe(publishableKey);

  const elements = stripe.elements({
    fonts: [{
      cssSrc: "https://rsms.me/inter/inter-ui.css"
    }],
    locale: "auto"
  });

  const style = {
    base: {
      color: "#32325d",
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontFamily: "Inter UI, Open Sans, Segoe UI, sans-serif",
      fontSize: "16px",
      fontSmoothing: "antialiased",

      "::placeholder": {
        color: "#CFD7DF"
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: "#E25950"
    }
  };

  const card = elements.create('card', { style });

  card.mount("#card-element");

  card.addEventListener('change', ( {error} ) => {
    const displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if(error) {
      displayError.textContent = error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = "";
    }
  });

  const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

  form.addEventListener('submit', async(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken(card);

    if (error) {
      const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = error.message;
    } else {
      stripeTokenHandler(token);
    }
  });


  const stripeTokenHandler = (token) => {
    const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    ["type", "last4", "exp_month", "exp_year"].forEach(function(field) {
      addCardField(form, token, field);
    });

    form.submit();
  }

  function addCardField(form, token, field) {
    let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', "user[card_" + field + "]");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.card[field]);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
  }

});
```

and here's my routes.rb (/config/routes.rb):

```
require 'sidekiq/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books do
    member do
      put "add", to: "books#library"
      put "remove", to: "books#library"
    end
  end
  resources :library, only:[:index]
  resources :pricing, only:[:index]
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
  root to: 'books#index'
  resources :subscriptions
end
```

And here's the console when the index error is showing
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDotx.png)

Any ideas will very helpful! Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to create a Subscription, and if I recall, that was an older way, but now you can - and should - create it [like this:](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=ruby)

```
Stripe::Subscription.create({
  customer: customer.id,
  items: [
    {price: plan.id},
  ],
})
```

Comment: I am still getting an undefined method error for subscription with that way too: 

undefined method `subscription' for Stripe:Module
Hint: `subscription` is being called on a `Module` object, which might not be the type of object you were expecting.

And also when i refresh the page i get the index error method, I dont need to define an index for this app so I dont understand why its asking me for one.

Comment: I’m pretty sure at this point is has to do with Stripe api, I read somewhere that I should use require ‘stripe’ but I am not sure where I should include that?

Comment: It worked! I just had to add subscription = ‘your code’ and its working perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome - glad to hear it! :)

Comment: @AbdulKadi What exactly did you add?